# VBScript Syntax Error in ArcGIS labeling?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, vbscript, syntax

I have been using a script on older ArcGIS to convert depths in engineering format to the Hydrographic format seen on charts.  On trying to use it I get a syntax error in Line 14.  No matter how I look I cannot see/find the error.

```vbs
Function FindLabel ([DEPTH])
  dim strSounding
  dim lngTrim
  dim lngDryHeight
  dim strSub

  lngDryHeight = instr([DEPTH],"-")
  lngTrim = instr([DEPTH],".")
  if lngTrim > 0 then
     strSub = right([DEPTH],1)
     strSounding = abs(left([DEPTH],lngTrim))
     if lngDryHeight > 0 then
        strSounding = "<UND>" & strSounding & "</UND>"
     end if
     strSounding = "<FNT name = ""Arial"" size=""7"">" & strSounding & "<SUB>" & strSub & "</SUB>" & "</FNT>"
  else
     if lngDryHeight > 0 then
        strSounding = "<UND>" & abs([DEPTH])  & "</UND>"
     else
        strSounding = abs([DEPTH])
     end if
     strSounding = "<FNT name = ""Arial"" size=""7"">" & strSounding & "</FNT>"
  end if

  FindLabel = "<ITA>" & strSounding & "</ITA>"
End Function
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample values from your `DEPTH` field?  When I try that code in ArcGIS 10.4 I find it works no problem, however my made-up values may be quite different to your values.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS?

Comment: Remove  "" or replace by " & "  ?

Comment: Thanks @Midavalo, I am using ArcGIS 10.4. Where would you like me to send a sample dataset

Comment: I have managed to find the error it was in the data file provided where the precision and scale had been set incorrectly and therefore the subroutine did not have enough decimal places to run.  Thank you for your advice

Comment: @IanDavies - glad you found the problem.  For future reference, we don't usually need actual data uploaded anywhere, but a screenshot of a sample of your data or table, or perhaps a few lines as text in your question, can help us replicate your setup to test.